# In python interpreter, os.system() always returns -1

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cmd

When I tried to clear the python shell with using following python commands.

```
import os
os.system("cls")
```

It always returned -1. Then I tried os.system() for different inputs. like,

```
os.system("cd ..")
os.system("mkdir hello")
```

But it fails all the time and **returns -1**.
Why is it so?

Comment: You could try `subprocess` instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

Comment: after importing subprocess module, I tried as subprocess.call("cls",shell = True). But it fails, with error "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem. I am posting the solution if someone faces the same problem in future.

In my case, environment variable ComSpec was modified automatically by Microsoft SQL server update. I did modify it to the previous value, that was "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe". After modifying this environment variable, logoff and login again.

Comment: Odd - what was it modified to?

Comment: It was  modified to "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;" I could not figure it out why the SQL server update modified this variable. I have two system. In another system, everything works just fine. So i compared the environment variable of both systems, and meanwhile I noticed the updated value of CompSec environment variable. So I did modify it to "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;", and it worked. :)